# Custom Theme Responsive/Mobile Disable and enable Full Site

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, multistore, rwd, mobile

Good Morning,

Our website has a custom theme by VenusThemes. I've looked through the guide or instructions to see if we could temporary disable the "mobile" side of theme to show only full site on both PC screen sizes and mobile devices. Not sure if its a theme feature or a Magento feature. At this point in the stage of our development i want to force full site mode for all devices. We will come back and revisit another alternative for a mobile site later on, so id rather disable it than remove it permanently so to speak.

How would i go about doing that? Please give detailed instructions if/as possible.

Our website is multi-store using one backend database. www.thepoultryhatchery.com

We are using Magento Community Edition 1.9

This is our theme --> http://www.venustheme.com/guides/ves_superstore/

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can see this happening is to edit your css and remove all the media queries.

eg:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { ....}
```

But exactly why one would want to do this is beyond me. Generally I would not visit any site on my mobile / tablet that only displays in full page view and isn't responsive.

So make sure you backup your css file(s) first, so you can replace them when you decide you want to have your responsive design back.

The media queries could be across a multiple of files. But as I do not know if your theme uses sass or less it is hard to tell as you've enabled css compression

Comment: Thank you! Do you suggest any other mobile extensions maybe that would produce a more user-friendly layout as an alternative?

Comment: I don't think you quite understand the basics of css and media queries. CSS is the style sheet that applies shapes, sizes, colours, fonts and anything else to do with style to the pretty standard magento layout.

A media query is a css code that only applied for specific widths or width-ranges.

If you dislike the responsive behaviour of your current theme, you could edit the media queries yourself, and hide or show elements for certain device widths - no extension can do this for you. You could install a seperate theme for mobiles only though.

Answer (score 2):

@tecjam Basically gives the right answer in your scenario, but I wanted to add some more detail for a better understanding.

Unfortunately this would be a theme-specific feature. You'll have to consult that manual for any clues, but its unlikely that it will have this ability with the flip of a switch.

Most themes these days are built on RWD -- responsive web design -- principles. As a component of it, scaling to screen sizes is determined by what are called *media queries in CSS*. As @tecjam suggests, to tweak this it would involve stripping out those areas of the theme's stylesheet.

Also, it doesn't make sense to do this, as you likely purchased the theme *because* of its RWD capabilities. It may also have some unintended effects that the theme wasn't built to acommodate.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Do you suggest any other mobile extensions maybe that would produce a more user-friendly layout?

Comment: Unfortunately such a question is way too subjective and is really outside of the scope of this site. This is something you should have weighed before committing to the purchase of the theme. I'm not condemning you, but rather pointing out how to evaluate these things ahead of time. I work primarily with custom builds, so I can't really give any advice about pre-built themes.